# How to call an item using java?

Tags: java, android

I have layer-list in my drawable and it contains an item that has a drawable that is assigned to it:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/first"
    android:id="@+id/first">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and I want to change the drawable of the item but by using java, any idea how to do this??

Comment: find the Drawable by id

Comment: @pskink what will i type, for example when you find a button by id you type Button name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name); what will I write instead of button?

Comment: what button?  what you mean?

Comment: I'm giving an example, how will I call for it and set a different image?

Comment: @pskink The item contains an image, ok. I want to change this image using java

Comment: see my first comment: find the Drawable by layer id, when you have the reference to your Drawable you can do whatever you want

Comment: @pskink what will I write?

Comment: oh read the javadocs of LayerDrawable